# Perl: Json Parsing from URL every time getting one value inside array

Tags: json, perl

**JSON RESPONSE:** Below is my json response which i am to parse from url.

```
[
    {
        "StationID": 17682,
        "TVEStationID": 0,
        "CallLetters": "DIYHD",
        "StationName": "DIYHD",
        "Affiliation": "Do-It-Yourself Network HD",
    },
    {
        "StationID": 17683,
        "TVEStationID": 0,
        "CallLetters": "WGNA",
        "StationName": "WGNA",
        "Affiliation": "WGN America HD",
    }
]
```

**Perl code :**

```
my $response = $ua->get('https://myurl here......');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;
}
```

I have to parse above json and store it into a variable for all five values, I am new in perl not able to find out the solution for this, Please help me to parse this.

Here, I am getting success response but inside the response how i have to parse and get the value... from array that i am not able to do.

Thankyou

Comment: What is the `get()` function you're calling on `$response`? What output are you getting? And what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: my response is coming , now i have edited my question. In response i am getting my json response, now how i have to parse please help me. @simbabque

Comment: @PrityKumari: So here `my $response = $ua->get('https://myurl here......');` you're getting the JSON response and you need to store in what? Parse it in which format? Shall we know how your output should look like from the response you're getting?

Comment: I have to store all values into variable insert into table, I am not able to irritate for loop and not able to get values, please help me @vkk05

Comment: @PrityKumari: Have a look into Dave's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636320/6124824) and print `Dumper` for `$data`. You will get response from the URL which is been mentioned in `$ua->get(..)` in very nice format. From there you can take forward how to insert it in table. You can open separate thread if parsing from `$data` becomes difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library, my preferred one is [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/Cpanel::JSON::XS), but see also [JSON::MaybeXS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::MaybeXS), [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS), and [JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

...
use Cpanel::JSON::XS;

my $response = $ua->get('https://myurl here......');
if ($response->is_success) {
    my $structure = decode_json($response->decoded_content);
    print $structure->[1]{StationID};  # 17683
}
```

Note that I had to remove the trailing commas from the JSON.

Comment: Hi @choroba I have to parse from URL , Please help me on that.

Comment: Just try calling `decode_json` on the $json variable in your code.

Comment: if ($response->is_success) {
my $structure1 = decode_json($response);
print $structure1->[1]{StationID};

I am using like above code , please check once.

Comment: But I have to parse fom API json response , not from only json

Comment: I don't understand. Please give more details.

Comment: @PrityKumari: But the HTTP response contains the JSON. You use `decoded_content()` to get the JSON string from the HTTP response, and then `decode_json()` to turn that JSON string into a Perl data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
use JSON;

my $response = $ua->get('https://myurl here......');

if ($response->is_success) {
  my $json = $response->decoded_content;

  my $data = JSON->new->decode($json);

  # $data now contains an array reference which contains
  # all of your data.
}
```